# Prisma asking for required ID which is marked as default(autoincrement() in schema

Tags: python, python-3.x, prisma

I'm using the Python Prisma client. Below is my `schema.prisma` which should make it so that whenever I create something in the `serververification` table, it will have an autoincremented ID on that inserted data.

The database is a MySQL database.

```
model serververification {
  id               Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  guildId          String  @db.VarChar(20)
  enabled          Boolean @db.Bit(1)
  panelMessageId   String? @db.VarChar(20)
  panelChannelId   String? @db.VarChar(20)
  logChannelId     String? @db.VarChar(20)
  unverifiedRoleId String? @db.VarChar(20)
  verifiedRoleIds  String? @db.LongText

  @@index([guildId], map: "guildId_fkey")
}
```

However, this does not seem to be the case. If I don't personally specify an ID I get an error stating that A value is required but not set. I'm not entirely sure what I've gone wrong. The schema is up to date with the database, I have ran all necessary commands

```
yarn prisma generate
yarn prisma db push
yarn prisma migrate dev
yarn prisma db pull
```

Code where I create the new data to insert into the database, notice how I do not include a `id` key value, because the schema specifies that it shouldn't require me to, since the field is an auto incremented integer ID.

```py
        await self.client.prisma.serververification.create(
            data={
                "guildId": str(interaction.guild_id),
                "enabled": True,
                "panelMessageId": str(panel_message.id),
                "panelChannelId": str(panel_channel_id.id),
                "logChannelId": None,
                "unverifiedRoleIds": str(unverified_role_id.id),
            }
        )
```

Python prisma version: v0.6.6
other version information:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.1.1",
    "prisma": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

error:

```
prisma.errors.FieldNotFoundError: Failed to validate the query: `Unable to match input value to any allowed input type for the field. Parse errors: [Query parsing/validation error at `Mutation.createOneserververification.data.serververificationCreateInput.unverifiedRoleIds`: Field does not exist on enclosing type., Query parsing/validation error at `Mutation.createOneserververification.data.serververificationUncheckedCreateInput.unverifiedRoleIds`: Field does not exist on enclosing type.]` at `Mutation.createOneserververification.data`
```

[image: HeidiSQL database structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema file, you defined a field called `unverifiedRoleId`. In your client when assigning a value to that field, you added an extra character `s` to the field name. Instead of `unverifiedRoleId`, you are using `unverifiedRoleIds`. Note the plural form here. To fix this issue, ensure both the field name in the schema file matches with the field name in the client.

schema.prisma file

```
model serververification {
  id               Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  guildId          String  @client.VarChar(20)
  enabled          Boolean @client.Bit(1)
  panelMessageId   String? @client.VarChar(20)
  panelChannelId   String? @client.VarChar(20)
  logChannelId     String? @client.VarChar(20)
  unverifiedRoleId String? @client.VarChar(20)
  verifiedRoleIds  String? @client.LongText

  @@index([guildId], map: "guildId_fkey")
}
```

main.py file

```
serververification = await db.serververification.create(
        data = {
                "guildId":"abcdefgh",
                "enabled": True,
                "panelMessageId": "12345678",
                "panelChannelId": "qwerty",
                "logChannelId": None,
                "unverifiedRoleId": "poiuyt",
        }
    )

    print(f'created serververification: {serververification.json(indent=2, sort_keys=True)}')

    found = await db.serververification.find_unique(where={'id': serververification.id})
    assert found is not None
    print(f'found serververification: {found.json(indent=2, sort_keys=True)}')
```

output

```
created serververification: {
  "enabled": true,
  "guildId": "abcdefgh",
  "id": 4,
  "logChannelId": null,
  "panelChannelId": "qwerty",
  "panelMessageId": "12345678",
  "unverifiedRoleId": "poiuyt",
  "verifiedRoleIds": null
}
found serververification: {
  "enabled": true,
  "guildId": "abcdefgh",
  "id": 4,
  "logChannelId": null,
  "panelChannelId": "qwerty",
  "panelMessageId": "12345678",
  "unverifiedRoleId": "poiuyt",
  "verifiedRoleIds": null
}
```